# GNU sed - use ":" as delimiter works while other common chars don't

Tags: bash, unix, sed, cygwin

I am using GNU bash in Windows 10 by Cygwin. `bash -version` gives me:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(7)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
```

Now, I want to use `sed` to process some files. While testing, I found something strange: my expression, while totally valid, works only when the delimiter is `:`. When the delimiter is `/` or `_` or `,`, it gives me unexpected result.

For example, I want to get rid of the `<>` in this string: `<Autorizado>`.

When I use:

```
echo "<Autorizado>" | sed -r 's:<([a-zA-Z]+)>:\1:'
```

I get:

```
Autorizado
```

But, when I change `:` to `/` or `_` or `,`, the result is:

```
1
```

I follow the tutorial here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

So, what happens here?

Comment: It would be more useful to know your version of sed - anyway, I can't reproduce on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.

Comment: I have checked with `where sed`, and I found two entries, the first is not what `cygwin` uses. Instead, it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\BMC Software\BladeLogic\8.1\NSH\bin\sed.exe`. Let me check this again..

Comment: `sed --version` should tell you, but I guess it's a version of GNU sed.

Comment: Delete the first from-nowhere entry makes my `cmd` not able to locate the binary, but `sed --version` and `where sed` can locate it. Strange enough. Time to reboot...

Comment: Can you paste the exact command line which returns `1`?

Comment: It must have been some problem with the first `sed` entry. Now when I deleted it, `cmd` cannot locate `sed.exe`, and cygwin terminal behaves correctly. Thx for help.

Comment: Not sure why you aren't just doing  `sed 's/[<>]//g'` to being with

Comment: @SaintHax thanks for help, this has to do with the first entry of `sed` in the path, not related to `sed` of gnu. But I want to know what does `sed 's/[<>]//g'` means.

Comment: @FaithReaper `sed 's/[<>]//g'` is switch all occurrences of < or > to nothing.  In other words, it removes them.

Comment: I think that in NSH sed the reference `\1` to the capture group is interpreted a the string `1`.  Probably a Windows thing and potentially fixed with `\\1` unless there is truly a sed which doesn't allow capture groups.